# Drupal Views & URL Alias Override Issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have a taxonomy vocabulary called 'catalogue'. Within this, I have levels of terms. Some have sub-terms, some have nodes.

I have two views to handle these: One to show sub categories, one to show nodes, each with a filter applied based on the URL. If I go to `sub-category/category-name`, it would show me all the sub-terms in category name. If I go to `product-category/category-name`, I get a list of related nodes.

With no aliases, the view works properly on `sub-category/%`. The problem with this is that the generated links for the sub-terms aren't to the view, they're to the term page.

If I create aliases, it overrides the view and shows no results on `sub-category/%` pages and default node teasers on `product-category/%`.

Can I use aliases with views in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to re-write the output of the Field instead of creating aliases.  If you're not familiar with that particular feature in Views, see the screenshot below from http://highrockmedia.com/blog/rewriting-drupal-views-output-custom-theming-css

Note that instead of creating a `<div>` wrapper, you can create your own link as needed.  Hopefully this will help you get started in the right direction.

[image: re-write field output]

Comment: It'll take a bit of figuring out and perhaps another level of categories (parent, sub and product) but this looks like it will do the job. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ScottBrown remember that you will have to include any field/tokens *above/before* the field that you are re-writing the output for.  Also, you can hide those fields/tokens that you are using from the display if they're only needed to create the URL.